# Execute custom script before integration tests

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

my application is using Spring Boot, with 2 main modules main and test. In another directory on same level I have folder which contains script with database triggers which I need create in database before tests.

Here is my project structure:

```
src/
├── main
├── scripts (this is not module, only default folder)
│   └── custom_script.sql
└── test
    └── persistent
        └── TestConfiguration.java
```

Test configuration is only interface where I set some configuration for tests, currently contains following code:

```
@Sql("../../scripts/custom_script.sql")
public interface TestConfiguration {
}
```

This code didn't work, and custom_script.sql isn't executed. Can you tell me why, or what is the better to execute it?

Comment: `src/main/scripts/custom_script.sql`

Comment: @DarrenForsythe not really, scripts is not in `src/main`...

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48909046/run-custom-script-after-database-tables-are-created-in-spring-boot