# Run custom script after database tables are created in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot with gradle in my project with following project structure:

```
src/
├── main
│   ├── java
│   └── resources
│       └── import.sql
├── scripts
│   └── custom_script.sql
└── test
    ├── java
    │   ├── persistent
    │   │   └── UserRepositoryTest.java
    │   └── TestConfiguration.java
    └── resources
        └── import.sql
```

in `custom_script.sql` I have some sql scripts which my application requires, e.g. triggers before inserts and so on. Is possible to configure application, for example with application properties file, with hibernate, or some another way to load that script and create my triggers after tables will be created?

Tables I have defined as JPA Entities. So my expected steps order is:

1. Create tables from JPA Entities
2. Load triggers from scripts/custom_script.sql
3. Load insert scripts from `resources/import.sql`
4. Run application / tests (it depends if I decide to run main app or tests)

For test purpose I tried create `TestConfiguration.java` interface where I use `@Sql` anotation like that:

```
@Sql("src/scripts/custom_script.sql")
public interface TestConfiguration {
}
```

and next I wanted to use this interface for tests which requires this script like that:

```
@Transactional
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class UserRepositoryTest implements TestConfiguration {

}
```

Problem is that :

1. my solution didn't work
2. it's cover only Test case, not case when application starts normally

Can you help me with that please? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure, but typically you do not want to recreate whole DB on startup. This is ok, for tests, but are you sure you want to delete previous data?

Comment: @Betlista You are right, primary I need this for Tests. Bur during application development I have set hibernate to create-drop. But if it not possible I will be grateful for solution which work only for Tests.

Comment: Have you considered to add liquibase to your project? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-execute-liquibase-database-migrations-on-startup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Sql` only works on Tests:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/jdbc/Sql.html

However you could try the following.
Add the script to your classpath by putting your scripts folder under src/test/resources

Then set the `@Sql`Annotation on your UserRepositoryTest Class and change the path to:

`@Sql("classpath:scripts/custom_script.sql")`

If you want to use it on other Tests please create an abstract testclass with the needed annotations.

If you need real Database migration have a look at Flyway: https://flywaydb.org/

Comment: Yes, if it will works with tests that it will be enough. But I need to use folder tree which I show in question. Is it possible execute script from there with SQL Anotation?

Comment: Yes. You have to use file: prefix instead of classpath:

Comment: I have same problem, but @SQL(file:scripts/custom_script.sql) doesn't work for me ... can you help me? Folder structure is same as well.

Comment: try using an absoulte path to your script

Answer (score 0):

Check out Flyway https://flywaydb.org/. This plugin allows database migration during startup and can perform various actions on your database to migrate from one version to another. This will do what you need.